# Pyspark: run a script from inside the archive

Tags: python, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have an archive (basically a bundled conda environment + my application) which I can easily use with pyspark in yarn master mode:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./pkg/venv/bin/python3 \ 
spark-submit \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./pkg/venv/bin/python3 \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--archives hdfs:///package.tgz#pkg \
app/MyScript.py
```

This works as expected, no surprise here.

Now how could I run this if MyScript.py is *inside* package.tgz. not on my local filesystem?

I would like to replace the last line of my command with eg. `./pkg/app/MyScript.py` but then spark complains: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/blah/pkg/app/MyScript.py does not exist`.

I could of course extract it first, put it separately on hdfs... There are workarounds but as I have everything in one nice place, I would love to use it.

If it's relevant, this is spark 2.4.0, python 3.7, on CDH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you cannot: you must supply a Python script to `spark-submit`.

But you can have a very short script and use `--py-files` to distribute a ZIP or EGG of the rest of your code:

```
# go.py

from my.app import run

run()
```

```
# my/app.py

def run():
  print("hello")
```

You can create a ZIP file containing the my directory and submit that with the short entry point script: `spark-submit --py-files my.zip go.py`

If you like, you can make a generic `go.py` that accepts arguments telling it which module and method to import and run.